# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" Error

Tags: c#, oop, nullreferenceexception, access-modifiers, object-reference

Im Having Problems Figuring Out Why I am Receiving an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" Error in the Presentation Layer with this line:

**TempAccountManager.Accounts.Add(tempAccount);**

I Have Walked Through the Code With Visual Studios Debugger and the Account Gets Created. I Believe I Have an Issue With an Access Modifer, Not Sure.

**Presentation Layer**

```
using myBudget.BusinessObject;
using myBudget.BusinessLogic;

namespace myBudget
{
    public partial class NewBudgetWizard : Form
    {

        public int CurrentStep { get; set; }

        public Account TempAccount = new Account();
        public AccountManager TempAccountManager = new AccountManager();

        public NewBudgetWizard()
        {

        private void createAccountList(ListView lvAccounts)
        {

            foreach (ListViewItem lvi in lvAccounts.Items)
            {

                int tempAccNumber = Int32.Parse(lvi.SubItems[0].Text);
                string tempAccName = lvi.SubItems[1].Text;
                string tempAccType = lvi.SubItems[2].Text;
                decimal tempAccBalance = decimal.Parse(lvi.SubItems[3].Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency);

                Account tempAccount = new Account(tempAccNumber, tempAccName, tempAccType, tempAccBalance, DateTime.Now);
                TempAccount = new Account(tempAccNumber, tempAccName, tempAccType, tempAccBalance, DateTime.Now);

                TempAccountManager.Accounts.Add(tempAccount);

            }

        }

    }
}
```

**Business Logic Layer**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using myBudget.BusinessObject;

namespace myBudget.BusinessLogic
{
    public class AccountManager : Account
    {

        public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Business Object**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace myBudget.BusinessObject
{
    public class Account
    {

        public int AccountID { get; set; }

        public int UserID { get; set; }

        public int Number { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Type { get; set; }

        public decimal Balance { get; set; }

        public DateTime ReconcileTimeStamp { get; set; }

        public Account()
        {

        }

        public Account(int number, string name, string type, decimal balance, DateTime reconcileTimeStamp)
        {
            Number = number;
            Name = name;
            Type = type;
            Balance = balance;
            ReconcileTimeStamp = reconcileTimeStamp;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `AccountManager` Class Never Initializes The `Accounts` Property. Therefore `TempAccountManager.Accounts` Is Null.

Adding A Constructor Like This Will Fix It.

```
public class AccountManager : Account
{
    public AccountManager()
    {
        Accounts = new List<Account>();
    }

    public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Thank You! Wish I could Vote for More then one Answer. Since You Posted the Answer Before and Have More Code I am Going to Submit as Answered.

Answer (score 3):

Do you create `Accounts` in your `AccountManager`?

You should do somewhere:

```
Accounts = new List<Account>();
```

**EDIT**

You've got public `set` accessor. You may do:

```
TempAccountManager.Accounts = new List<Account>();
```

Or add a constructor to the class, as Joel Mueller suggested. But think over, if you need the public `set`. It gives an opportunity to completely replace your collection out of the object.

Comment: No I Did Not. Would I do that in the Property?

Comment: Thank You! Fixed. I wish I can Vote for One Correct Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but where do you initialize Accounts?

```
public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
```

Your get, set interface provides access, but doesn't define the value.